# Подключения к запущенному Com-объекту в .net-5

Tags: c#, com, .net-5

Раньше .net-4 для подключения к запущенному Com-объекту
использовал метод **GetActiveObject**

```
string progId = "KOMPAS.Application.7";
(_Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject(progId);
```

Сейчас в .net-5
VS пишет -

> CS0117: "Marshal" не содержит определение для .GetActiveObject(progId)

Собственно вопрос:

Как подключится к запущенному Com-объекту в **.net-5**

Comment: измените целевой фреймворк в cproj файле с `net5.0` на `net5.0-windows`.

Comment: Благодарю за совет, но Отладчик пишет: Ошибка NETSDK1139 не удалось распознать идентификатор целевой платформы window

Comment: `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>` вот так должно быть.

Comment: К сожалению не выходит. Пробовал и в старом проекте менять и вновь создавать проект, где сначала изменил платформу, откомпилировал и только затем наполнял взаимодействие с Com объектами. Не идет - пишет ту же ошибку - ""Marshal" не содержит определение для .GetActiveObject"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Огромное спасибо коллегам из
[Cyberforum](https://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread2762697.html)

Задача решена:

1. Надо выдрать функцию **GetActiveObject**(String progID)
   из исходников [Github.Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs#L2404)
2. Создать свой класс, к примеру - Marshal2
3. И использовать как раньше

   Marshal2.GetActiveObject(progID);

Исходный код

```
public static class Marshal2
{
    internal const String OLEAUT32 = "oleaut32.dll";
    internal const String OLE32 = "ole32.dll";

    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated_required
    public static Object GetActiveObject(String progID)
    {
        Object obj = null;
        Guid clsid;

        // Call CLSIDFromProgIDEx first then fall back on CLSIDFromProgID if
        // CLSIDFromProgIDEx doesn't exist.
        try
        {
            CLSIDFromProgIDEx(progID, out clsid);
        }
        //            catch
        catch (Exception)
        {
            CLSIDFromProgID(progID, out clsid);
        }

        GetActiveObject(ref clsid, IntPtr.Zero, out obj);
        return obj;
    }

    //[DllImport(Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.OLE32, PreserveSig = false)]
    [DllImport(OLE32, PreserveSig = false)]
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
    private static extern void CLSIDFromProgIDEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String progId, out Guid clsid);

    //[DllImport(Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.OLE32, PreserveSig = false)]
    [DllImport(OLE32, PreserveSig = false)]
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
    private static extern void CLSIDFromProgID([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String progId, out Guid clsid);

    //[DllImport(Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.OLEAUT32, PreserveSig = false)]
    [DllImport(OLEAUT32, PreserveSig = false)]
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
    private static extern void GetActiveObject(ref Guid rclsid, IntPtr reserved, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out Object ppunk);

}
```